# Using ansible cli to restart servers return an error (while still restarting the servers)

Tags: ssh, ansible

I can successfully connect to my server with ssh. Nevertheless, when I try to execute a command through Ansible cli, it fails:

```
ansible en2 -a "/sbin/reboot" -vvv
Using /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg as config file
<en2> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: None
<en2> SSH: EXEC ssh -C -q -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/home/buzut/.ansible/cp/ansible-ssh-%h-%p-%r en2 '/bin/sh -c '"'"'( umask 77 && mkdir -p "` echo $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1470744750.87-182962282383475 `" && echo ansible-tmp-1470744750.87-182962282383475="` echo $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1470744750.87-182962282383475 `" ) && sleep 0'"'"''
<en2> PUT /tmp/tmpampMBF TO /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1470744750.87-182962282383475/command
<en2> SSH: EXEC sftp -b - -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/home/buzut/.ansible/cp/ansible-ssh-%h-%p-%r '[en2]'
<en2> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: None
<en2> SSH: EXEC ssh -C -q -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/home/buzut/.ansible/cp/ansible-ssh-%h-%p-%r -tt en2 '/bin/sh -c '"'"'LANG=fr_FR.UTF-8 LC_ALL=fr_FR.UTF-8 LC_MESSAGES=fr_FR.UTF-8 /usr/bin/python /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1470744750.87-182962282383475/command; rm -rf "/root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1470744750.87-182962282383475/" > /dev/null 2>&1 && sleep 0'"'"''
en2 | UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false, 
    "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh.", 
    "unreachable": true
}
```

Comment: Hint: it's not the user as `USER: None` defaults to root and that's how it' supposed to connect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything in your output looks correct.

Ansible establishes an SSH connection, runs its script (containing your command) and waits for its exit code.

However you order it to issue an `/sbin/reboot` command which reboots the server. The SSH connection is thus broken before the exit code is returned to the Ansible and Ansible reports the error.

The error message is actually a bit misleading, but it means the connection was broken.

Comment: What's weird is that it just works as expected on some servers and not others. Nevertheless, it worked on a server doing `ansible -m ping`. So you must just be right!

Comment: You can confirm that by checking of the server restarted.

Comment: Definitely! That's what I'll do.

Comment: SSH doesn't really keep the session packets constantly flowing, depending on the configuration it might poll the server at several-minute intervals and renegotiate the session.  I'm not sure if it can survive daemon (server) restart. That would explain why sometimes you don't get the error. You made me curious about that.

Comment: Yes, I don't really understand why some servers error and others not. As they're all the same config: Ubuntu 16.04 set up with ansible of course and same ssh conf for all. It might be hardware bound then? I also confirm that the servers restarted!